# Upgrading Delphi 7 Indy 9 app. to Indy 10

Tags: delphi, indy10

I have inherited an extensive (199 commands) Delphi 7 Indy 9 app that I am upgrading to Indy 10 (in D10.1). I have upgraded all the code, and it compiles and runs. The problem I have is that now in Indy 10 all the handlers *also return a response code* (and text) in addition to the coded response that they did under Indy 9.

For example:

```
// server 
procedure TFormMain.IdCmdTCPServer1loginCommand(ASender: TIdCommand);
var
  Rights: String;
begin

   if BillingUserRegistered(ASender.Params[0], ASender.Params[1], Rights) then
   begin
      myClient := TClientData.Create;
      myClient.ClientName := ASender.Params[0];
      myClient.ClientHost := #32; // indy9 was .Thread.Connection.LocalName; 
      myClient.ID := Now;
      ASender.Context.Data := myClient;

      ListBox1.Items.AddObject(
        PadR(myClient.ClientName,12,' ') + '=' +
        FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss', myClient.ID),
        TDateTimeO.Create(myClient.ID));
      ASender.Context.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('SUCCESS' + ' ' + Rights)  
  end
  else
      ASender.Context.Connection.IOHander.WriteLn('Login failed!');

end;
```

...

```
// client side
function TfrmLogin.VerifyUserNameAndPassword(username, password: String): Boolean;
var
  response, response1: String;
begin

  frmMain.IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn('login' + ' ' + 
     username + ' ' + password)
  response := frmMain.IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn();
  // I have to add this now to capture the response code too!
  response1 := frmMain.IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn(); // 200 OK
  // ------------------------------------------------------
  if Copy(response,1,7) = 'SUCCESS' then
  begin
    rights := Copy(response,9,4);
```

There are a lot of command handlers, and they all have their own custom responses. That's a lot of code to change at the client. Is there a way I can tell the `IdCmdTCPServer` to suppress the standard '200 Ok' response if the command handler already provides it's own? Or am I in for a long night?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to suppress the default command responses, you can either:

1. clear the `TIdCommandHandler`'s `ReplyNormal` and `ExceptionReply` properties (this also works in Indy 9, except that `ExceptionReply` was `ReplyExceptionCode` in that version), and the server's `CommandHandlers.ExceptionReply` property (Indy 10 only).
2. set the `TIdCommand.PerformReply` property to false in your `OnCommand` handler (this also works in Indy 9):

   ```
   procedure TFormMain.IdCmdTCPServer1loginCommand(ASender: TIdCommand);
   var
     ...
   begin
     ASender.PerformReply := False;
     ...
   end;
   ```
3. set the server's `CommandHandlers.PerformReplies` property to false (Indy 10 only - it will set `TIdCommand.PerformReply` to false by default):

   ```
   IdCmdTCPServer1.CommandHandlers.PerformReplies := False;
   ```

On the other hand, you should consider using the command handler responses the way they are designed to be used, eg:

```
procedure TFormMain.IdCmdTCPServer1loginCommand(ASender: TIdCommand);
var
  Rights: String;
begin
  if ASender.Params.Count = 2 then
  begin
    if BillingUserRegistered(ASender.Params[0], ASender.Params[1], Rights) then
    begin
      ...
      ASender.Reply.SetReply('SUCCESS', Rights);
    end
    else
      ASender.Reply.SetReply('ERROR', 'Login failed!');
  end
  else
    ASender.Reply.SetReply('ERROR', 'Wrong number of parameters!');
end;
```

I would even go as far as saying that you should set the `TIdCommandHandler.NormalReply.Code` property to `SUCCESS` and the `TIdCommandHandler.ExceptionReply.Code` property to `ERROR`, and then you can do this inside your `OnCommand` handler:

```
procedure TFormMain.IdCmdTCPServer1loginCommand(ASender: TIdCommand);
var
  Rights: String;
begin
  if ASender.Params.Count <> 2 then
    raise Exception.Create('Wrong number of parameters!');

  if not BillingUserRegistered(ASender.Params[0], ASender.Params[1], Rights) then
    raise Exception.Create('Login failed!');

  ...

  ASender.Text.Text := Rights;
end;
```

With that said, any of these approaches should work fine without changing your existing client code.  However, in Indy 10, I would suggest using `SendCmd()` instead of `WriteLn()`/`ReadLn()` directly:

```
function TfrmLogin.VerifyUserNameAndPassword(username, password: String): Boolean;
var
  response: String;
begin
  response := frmMain.IdTCPClient1.SendCmd('login ' + username + ' ' + password);
  if response = 'SUCCESS' then
  begin
    rights := frmMain.IdTCPClient1.LastCmdResult.Text.Text;
    ...
  end else begin
    // error message in frmMain.IdTCPClient1.LastCmdResult.Text.Text ...
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, you can let `SendCmd()` raise an exception if it does not receive a `SUCCESS` reply:

```
function TfrmLogin.VerifyUserNameAndPassword(username, password: String): Boolean;
begin
  try
    frmMain.IdTCPClient1.SendCmd('login ' + username + ' ' + password, 'SUCCESS');
  except
    on E: EIdReplyRFCError do begin
      // error message in E.Message ...
      ...
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  rights := frmMain.IdTCPClient1.LastCmdResult.Text.Text;
  ...
end;
```

`SendCmd()` does exist in Indy 9, but it only supports numeric-based response codes, which you are not using.  As you can see above, `SendCmd()` in Indy 10 supports string-based response codes as well as numeric ones.

---

On a side note: in your server code, the `OnCommand` handler runs in a worker thread, so your use of `ListBox1.Items.AddObject()` is not thread-safe.  Any access to the UI **must** be synchronized with the main UI thread, using techniques like `TThread.Synchronize()`, `TThread.Queue()`, `TIdSync`, `TIdNotify`, etc, eg:

```
procedure TFormMain.IdCmdTCPServer1loginCommand(ASender: TIdCommand);
var
  Rights: String;
  myClient: TClientData;
begin
  if ASender.Params.Count = 2 then
  begin
    if BillingUserRegistered(ASender.Params[0], ASender.Params[1], Rights) then
    begin
      myClient := TClientData(ASender.Context.Data);
      if myClient = nil then
      begin
        myClient := TClientData.Create;
        ASender.Context.Data := myClient;
      end;

      myClient.ID := Now;
      myClient.ClientName := ASender.Params[0];

      myClient.ClientHost := GStack.HostByAddress(ASender.Context.Binding.PeerIP, ASender.Context.Binding.IPVersion);
      // In Indy 9, this would be:
      // myClient.ClientHost := GStack.WSGetHostByAddr(ASender.Thread.Connection.Socket.PeerIP);
      // NOT ASender.Thread.Connection.LocalName!

      TThread.Queue(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          ListBox1.Items.AddObject(
            PadR(myClient.ClientName,12,' ') + '=' + FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss', myClient.ID),
            TDateTimeO.Create(myClient.ID));
        end
      );

      ASender.Reply.SetReply('SUCCESS', Rights);
    end
    else
      ASender.Reply.SetReply('ERROR', 'Login failed!');
  end
  else
    ASender.Reply.SetReply('ERROR', 'Wrong number of parameters!');
end;
```

Make sure your `BillingUserRegistered()` function is similarly thread-safe, if it is not already.

Comment: Brilliant answer. If you haven't written a book yet, when are you going to?

Comment: Yes, I agree. That was a very complete answer for which I'm grateful. The Delphi community would find an Indy guide book very useful. Until then, we have SO.