# Upgrading Delphi 7 Indy 9 app to Indy 10 (II)

Tags: delphi, indy

This is a follow-up question to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114391).

A lot of the commands and the responses are coded as delimited strings. 
In Delphi 7 these are typically coded using chr(166) and chr(167).

```
procedure TFormMain.IdTCPServer1InsertAccount(
  ASender: TIdCommand);
var
  cmd: String;
  request: String;
  Params: TMyStrings;
  AccountNo, Address, UserName: String;
begin
  cmd := 'InsertAccount';
  request := Copy(ASender.Rawline, Length(cmd) + 2, Length(ASender.RawLine));
  Params := TMyStrings.Create;
  try
    AssignDelimited(chr(166), request, Params);
    AccountNo := Params[0];
    Address := replace(char(167), #13#10, Params[1])
    UserName := Params[2];
```

It appears that this was done so that parameters can contain spaces. Similarly, commands whose content came from memo controls have their carriage return-line feeds replaced with chr(167) so the memo contents can be sent without terminating the command:

```
// typical client code
request := edAccountNo.Text + chr(166) + 
  replace(#13, chr(167), replace(#10, '', memoAddress.Lines.Text) + 
  chr(166) + Fusername;

idTCPClient1.WriteLn('InsertAccount' + space + request);
```

Now in converting this code to Delphi 10.1 with Indy 10, I did a search-and-replace chr(166) with ANSIChar(166), but I soon discovered that Indy 10 doesn't "like" ANSIChars higher than 127. The request appears correct at the client but is received at the server with ?'s

What's the best approach to upgrading this code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indy 10 is `UnicodeString`-aware, whereas Indy 9 is not.  Delphi 2009 and later versions use `UnicodeString` for their native `string` type, whereas Delphi 2007 and earlier versions use `AnsiString` instead.

Indy 9 transmits `AnsiString` data as-is as 8-bit data.  Indy 10 converts `AnsiString`/`UnicodeString` characters to bytes using charset conversions and then transmits the bytes.

Indy 10's default charset is ASCII, where any Unicode character above U+007F will get converted to 0x3F.  You are using characters greater than U+007F for your parameter delimiters, so the default ASCII charset is converting them to `?`, breaking your protocol.  It would have been safer to use ASCII control characters < U+0020 instead, such as U+0001.

To address this issue without changing your protocol, you can set Indy 10 to use its built-in 8bit charset for string <-> byte conversions (as long as you don't ever need to send Unicode characters > U+00FF in your protocol).  To do that, you can either:

1. set the connection's `IOHandler.DefStringEncoding` property to `IndyTextEncoding_8Bit` after the client connects to your server.  Do this on both the client and server sides of the connection:

   ```
   procedure TFormMain.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
   begin
     AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_8Bit;
   end;
   ```

   ```
   idTCPClient1.Connect;
   idTCPClient1.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_8Bit;
   ```
2. set Indy's global `GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable in the `IdGlobal` unit to `enc8Bit`.

   ```
   procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     GIdDefaultTextEncoding := enc8Bit;
   end;
   ```
3. When calling `IOHandler.WriteLn()` on the client side, you can pass `IndyTextEncoding_8Bit` in its optional `AByteEncoding` parameter.

   ```
   idTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn('InsertAccount' + space + request, IndyTextEncoding_8Bit);
   ```

   On the server side, assigning the connection's `IOHandler.DefStringEncoding` property would be best, or at least setting the `GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable.  But, as an alternative, you could derive a new component from `TIdCmdTCPServer` (or even use an interposer class) and override its virtual `ReadCommandLine()` method to call the connection's `IOHandler.ReadLn()` method specifying `IndyTextEncoding_8Bit` in its optional `AByteEncoding` parameter:

   ```
   type
     TIdCmdTCPServer = class(IdCommandHandlers.TIdCmdTCPServer)
     protected
       function ReadCommandLine(AContext: TIdContext): string; override;
     end;

     TFormMain = class(TForm)
       IdTCPServer1: TIdCmdTCPServer;
       ...
     end;

     ...

     function TIdCmdTCPServer.ReadCommandLine(AContext: TIdContext): string;
     begin
       Result := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_8Bit);
     end;
   ```

---

FYI, on a side note, `TCommandHandler` has a `ParamDelimiter` property.  If you set it to `#166` (it is `#32` by default) and set `ParseParams` to True, you can remove your `AssignDelimited()` function and let `TIdCommandHandler` parse your delimited parameters into the `TIdCommand.Params` property before firing its `OnCommand` event.

It might even be possible to go a step further by deriving a new class from `TIdCommandHandler` and override its virtual `DoParseParams()` method to handle the `#167 -> CRLF` conversions, instead of doing that manually in each `OnCommand` event handler.

Comment: Thank you for always providing a complete answer to my questions.